# Unity Loadscene link errors

Tags: unity, c#, scenemanager

I am working on a mobile game, and am experiencing a strange bug/error. When I load into the main scene , all is fine everything works and no errors. However there are two scenario's in which it breaks

- when I open the pause menu and go to the main menu. Then return to the level  all is broken.
- coming directly from the main menu into the level

GameObject links in scripts are missing and some other stuff. Here are the errors and corresponding code that is used:

[image]

If some screen from the editor are required I will update the question

Code used for the pause menu:

```
 public class Pause : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]private bool _isPaused;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _attackButton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _moveButton;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _pauseMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _pauseButton;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _isPaused = false;
        _pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void OnClickPauseButton()
    {
        _isPaused = !_isPaused;
        if(_isPaused)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            HideButtons();
        }
    }

    public void OnClickResumeButton()
    {
        _isPaused = !_isPaused;
        if (!_isPaused)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            ShowButtons();
        }
    }

    public void OnClickMenuButton()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

    private void HideButtons()
    {
        _attackButton.SetActive(false);
        _moveButton.SetActive(false);
        _pauseButton.SetActive(false);
        _pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void ShowButtons()
    {
        _attackButton.SetActive(true);
        _moveButton.SetActive(true);
        _pauseButton.SetActive(true);
        _pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

The Main menu code, that is used

```
 public void StartGame()
 {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("2DScene");
 }

 public void ClickUnfinishedButton()
 {
        StartCoroutine("FadeInAndOutText");
 }

 IEnumerator FadeInAndOutText()
 {
        toBeAddedText.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        toBeAddedText.SetActive(false);
}
```

EDIT:

Scoremanager code:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private PlayerController _player;
[SerializeField] private GameObject text;
[SerializeField] private Slider SliderVar;
private int _currentScore, _requiredScore;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    InitializeVariables();


}

private void InitializeVariables()
{
    _player = _player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    _requiredScore = 10;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    setScoreSlider();
    text.GetComponent<Text>().text = _player._currentScore + "/" + _requiredScore;
}



private void setScoreSlider()
{
    SliderVar.value = _player._currentScore / _requiredScore;
}
}
```

Code from inputscript:

```
 public class InputScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FingersJoystickScript joystickScript;
    [SerializeField] private float _minimumDistanceSwipe;
    [SerializeField] private float _minimumSpeedSwipe;
    [SerializeField] private SwipeGestureRecognizerDirection _swipeDirection;
    public GameObject player;
    public bool isAttacking;
    private TapGestureRecognizer _pressGestureRecognizer;
    private Vector2 _smoothDirection;
    private SwipeGestureRecognizer _swipeGestureRecognizer;
    private LongPressGestureRecognizer _longPressGestureRecognizer;
    private bool _facingRight = false;
    private Animator anim;



    private GestureTouch FirstTouch(ICollection<GestureTouch> touches)
    {
        foreach (var t in touches)
        {
            return t;
        }
        return new GestureTouch();
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        joystickScript.JoystickExecuted = JoystickExecuted;
        joystickScript.MoveJoystickToGestureStartLocation = false; 
        isAttacking = false;
    }

    //  public bool MoveJoysticktoGestureStartLocation;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
        CreateSwipeGesture();

        _swipeGestureRecognizer.MinimumDistanceUnits = _minimumDistanceSwipe;
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.MinimumSpeedUnits = _minimumSpeedSwipe;
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.Direction = _swipeDirection;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.MinimumDistanceUnits = _minimumDistanceSwipe;
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.MinimumSpeedUnits = _minimumSpeedSwipe;
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.Direction = _swipeDirection;


    }

    private void CreateSwipeGesture()
    {
        _swipeGestureRecognizer = new SwipeGestureRecognizer
        {
            Direction = SwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Any,
            DirectionThreshold = 1.0f
        };
        _swipeGestureRecognizer.Updated += SwipeGestureCallback;
        FingersScript.Instance.AddGesture(_swipeGestureRecognizer);
    }

    private void SwipeGestureCallback(GestureRecognizer gesture, ICollection<GestureTouch> touches)
    {
        if (gesture.State == GestureRecognizerState.Ended)
        {
            isAttacking = true;
        }

    }

    private void JoystickExecuted(FingersJoystickScript script, Vector2 amount)
    {
        if (amount.x > 0 && !_facingRight)
        {
            FlipXAxis();
        }
        else if (amount.x < 0 && _facingRight)
        {
            FlipXAxis();
        }
        Vector3 pos = player.transform.position;
        pos.x += (amount.x * 8 * Time.deltaTime);
        pos.z += (amount.y * 8 * Time.deltaTime);
        player.transform.position = pos;
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);

        if (amount == Vector2.zero)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
    }

    private void FlipXAxis()
    {
        //oposite direction
        _facingRight = !_facingRight;

        //get local scale
        var theScale = player.transform.localScale;

        //flip on x axis
        theScale.x *= -1;

        //apply that to the local scale
        player.transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
```

}

Comment: As I cant see your full code from InputScript and ScoreManager I will just guess here, so correct me if I am wrong. Sounds like Unity is destroying old scene and value when enter main menu scene and when rebuilding game scene you are not reinitiating your values and therefore UnassignedReference and NullReferenceException.

Comment: Updated the question with code from scoremanager/inputscript

Comment: Ok so the first and most obvious one is `InitializeVariables`, you can't `GetComponent` from a variable that is already `NULL` and **InputScript.cs** shows only _8_ lines of code here and your error is on line _36_.

Comment: Added the complete class

Comment: As mentioned when normally launching all is connected just fine, it only happens once I have swapped scenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Null Pointer Exceptions for all of those errors.

Basically you are trying to use variables that you haven't initialized.
For any private variable, you have to get a handle to the object with FindGameObject methods in your Start() before you can use it.

Your first error, for instance is at

```
private void InitializeVariables()
{
    _player = _player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    _requiredScore = 10;
}
```

_player is still null, because you havent initialized it with FindGameObject like so

```
GameObject p=GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
if(p!=null)
    _player=p.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
```

From that point on, you need to always preface any calls to _player with

```
if(_player != null)
```

In order to be safe if for some reason no object is tagged as Player

Comment: The menu works fine, it is other gameobjects/script that get removed

Comment: Updated to make it more clear whats going on. Be very careful what your making calls against. the example i used is bad for more reasons than a null point. For one, you effectively tried to get a handle to _player by assuming you already had a handle to _player. Secondly, a component cannot have a component. You essentially wrote "Component.getComponent()"